# how to check success data in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have called a php function using jquery and my function is working fine but the ajax success function is creating problem as I'm not able to reset the form data on success

I have tried `if(data.status == 'success'){ }` format too but it didn't work

```
$.ajax({        
        url:$wpajax,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',        
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data)
        {                            
           if(data['success']){
                $('#enquiry')[0].reset();
                location.reload(true);

            }
            else{

                location.reload(false);              
            }                    

        }
    });
```

No errors visible

Comment: can you share `data`?

Comment: Why use Ajax in the first place if you just reload the page. Also why do you think location.reload does when it is passed true and when it is passed false?

Comment: I'm reloading the page just for testing purpose. I have to reset the form and show a message of success or failure

Comment: console your response and update?

Comment: You cannot see if the form is reset if you reload the page

Comment: I agree with @SandeepK. console your response for you know the content of your `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is:

```
$.ajax({        
        url:$wpajax,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',        
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data)
        {                            
           if(data['success']){
                $('#enquiry')[0].reset();
                location.reload(true);
            }
            else{
                location.reload(false);              
            }                    
        }
    });
```

Use instead of this

```
$.ajax({        
        url:$wpajax,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',        
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data)
        {     
           alert(data);                       
           if(data['success']){
                $('#enquiry')[0].reset();
                location.reload(true);
            }
            else{
                location.reload(false);              
            }                    
        },
         error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) { // error callback 
         alert('Error: ' + errorMessage);        
         }
    });
```

If you get alert on error section. You will find the actual error and then solve it.
Also show your code behind so we will explain you better.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1

Comment: @Surya Yadav  Okay!!  In Success section or Error Section ??

Comment: Please find what is in the data with console log or alert

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1.     I'm getting this error in error section

Comment: May be your formdata is not proper. could you show us formdata code

Answer (score 0):

```
at your PHP function where ajax call put JSON return code

return response()->json(array('success' => 'true','result' => 
$result)); 

and than in your ajax success
$.ajax({        
    url:$wpajax,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',        
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(data)
    {                            
       if(data.success == 'true'){
            $('#enquiry')[0].reset();
            location.reload(true);

        }
        else{

            location.reload(false);              
        }                    

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it might possible that the endpoint is returning the json string rather than object.

try this:

```
success:function(data)
{
   data = JSON.parse(data);                 
   if(data.success){
```